# What is the difference between X-Content-Length and Content-Length?

Tags: http

I am seeing some APIs which take Content-Length and some which take X-Content-Length. When to use which header and can I define a header named X-Content-Type?

Answer (score 2):

X- was historically put as prefix on non-standard headers, so that when they later was standardized, the parameter syntax could change, and there would be no conflict. The X- prefix usage in general is deprecated, and should not be used